# Why is my hover only working on some of the polygon/path edges?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a `svg` that I want to highlight a `path/polygon` on `hover`.  Here is my `html`:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #c00;
}
svg polygon:hover {
  fill:  rgba(73,143,226,0.80);
}
```

```html
 <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2986 886" enable-background="new 0 0 2986 886">
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" strokeWidth="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="2289.1,543.6 2632.4,599 2546.8,421.2
        2183.8,302.3 " id="15"></polygon>
      <polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" strokeWidth="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="2182.9,300.3 2545.8,419.2 2426,170.2
        2148.2,0 2035.7,-1 " id="22"></polygon>
        ...
        ...
    </svg>
```

On the first `polygon`, the `hover fill` gets added on `hover`.  On the second `polygon` I have to run the mouse along the edge of the `polygon` to get the `hover` to work.  What can I do to make the `hover` always work?

Comment: You need to round out your example further. There is nothing here that suggests anything should/would happen on hover. I see `{this.props.click}` but have no idea what it is. Also, if the image isn't necessary to the example maybe just remove it.

Comment: Is the `image` unnecessary to the example?  It is the `background` that I am `hover` ing over.  Point noted on the `onClick`.  It is removed.  Also, added my `css`.

Comment: How should I know if the image is necessary??? It's your markup! LOL. Anyway, in this example, nothing is expected to happen when the user hovers over the background.

Comment: If I wasn't unsure, then I wouldn't be on `SO` asking a question.